# How to make all featured videos autoplay in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, video, autoplay

I have a page in wordpress with multiple videos and I want to make all videos autoplay, muted and loop. (I can't add the attributes manually because they are featured videos of blog posts so I need a script to do it automatically)
I used this script on the page:

```
  var vid = document.querySelector('video.wp-video-shortcode');
  vid.pauseOtherPlayers = false;
  vid.autoplay = true;
  vid.load();
  vid.muted = true;
  vid.loop = true;
```

But it works only for the first video, and I need it to be valid for all the videos. How can I fix it?

Comment: the code is "var vid = document.querySelectorAll......

Comment: You can try unique variables for all videos... `var vid1`  and `var vid2` and `var vid3` etc.

Comment: No I can't use unique variables because is a dynamic page and content can change. 
I tried with document.querySelectorAll but it doesn't work (for no element on the page).